# Search a specific post category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with two post categories: **News** and **Blog**.

I would like to have a search field to search only for posts in the News category. What is the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: You should list out what you have tried so far.